# HBase export task mysteriously stopped logging to output file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, export, hbase, hdfs

I recently attempted to do an export of a table from an HBase instance using a 10 data node Hadoop cluster. The command line looked like the following:

```
nohup hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export documents /export/documents 10 > ~/documents_export.out &
```

As you can see, I nohup the process so it wouldn't prematurely die when my SSH session closed, and I put the whole thing in the background. To capture the output, I directed it to a file.

As expected, the process started to run and in fact ran for several hours before the output mysteriously stopped in the file I was outputting to. It stopped at about 31% through the mapping phase of the mapreduce job being run. However, per Hadoop, the mapreduce job itself was still going and in fact was working to completion the next morning.

So, my question is why did output stop going to my log file? My best guess is that the parent HBase process I invoked exited normally when it was done with the initial setup for the mapreduce job involved in the export.

Comment: I doubt your disk space is filled, where the log file is present. I always to like `nohup`  like you did for MR & Spark but I have encountered the case when disk space is filled.

Comment: Thanks, ya, no disk space issues.